# Anchoring a Form within a Tab Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Form1 with a tab control in it. In this tab control i have inserted Form2. I have anchored the components in Form2 and that works fine. But as soon as i insert Form2 into Form1's tab control nothing happens when I resize the window. This is how I insert Form2 into Form1:

```
  public void AddNewForm(Form form, TabPage tab)
        {

            form.TopLevel = false;
            form.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Left);
            //form.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            form.Parent = tab;
            form.Show();

        }
```

As you can see I have tried to anchor and dock Form2 but nothing helps.

Can anyone help with this ?

Comment: I would try moving Form2's contents (controls and logic) to a user control and then use that control in both the tab and Form2

Comment: have u set parent form's IsMdiContainer to true and also set form.MdiParent to the parent form?

Comment: @w0lf - i was hoping that i could work around that. cuz Form2 is code writtin in .net 2.0, and is shitty code :)

Comment: @mihirj - Just tried and the form2 doesnt appear when i do that.

Comment: Having a form inside a control is not really a supported scenario, although it works to an extent. UserControl is what you want. If you may have this form appear separately, you can drop the same UserControl into it. When you need embedded, you'll use a UserControl, otherwise your wrapper form. I am saying wrapper, because it will have no logic, everything will be done by a UserControl it contains.

Answer (score 1):

The form is anchored/docked to the tab page.  Getting it to change size requires changing the size of the tab page.  So nothing happens to it when you resize Form1 unless you **also** anchor/dock the TabControl to make it change size.

Comment: i docked my tab control to Form1 and nothing happened. But i have moved the logic and design to a User Control that works fine. thanks for the help though. !